# Cannot Boot From USB

Tags: uefi, live-usb

I created an Ubuntu LiveUSB and when I reboot my computer I get no option to boot from it.

I have Secure Boot disabled. There are no fastboot or quickboot options in my BIOS settings.

I have Windows as the lowest on the boot order.

My system boots in UEFI. When I switch it to Legacy, it runs Ubuntu automatically on reboot and I have no option to run Windows.

I formatted my USB with NTFS using Windows' formatting utility.

I created the LiveUSB using the recommended Universal USB Installer.

[This is my laptop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HSYS3LO)

Comment: It sounds like you can boot from USB, *"When I switch it to Legacy, it runs Ubuntu automatically on reboot"*. What's the problem? Maybe you want to read everything here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: Yeah I have looked at that for hours. I reformatted the USB and then used Universal USB Installer and used its formatting which uses fat32. I then restarted and Grub comes up so that is great but now it won't let me pick Windows, I have to go into BIOS and change the boot order

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can not boot windows, right? Last installing ubuntu os, i also met the same problem. I have solved it by these steps. Here is that:

1. First, you must close the `security boot` and `fastboot` options in bios.
2. In terminal, to do `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`.
3. To do `sudo apt-get update`
4. To do 'sudo apt-get install boot-repair' for installing boot-repair.
5. After installed it, you should do `sudo boot-repair`.
6. Then, reboot your pc. You can see that the list `windows8 UEFI` of grub lists in screen. Choose it, and enter.
   Now, if everything is ok, your windows will can works well.